# ExecuteScalar devuelve Id Null ASP.NET

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy tratando de crear un sistema de comentarios en un proyecto personal y me surgió el siguiente inconveniente, al querer generar un comentario nuevo no me reconoce el Id del comentario y el `ExecuteScalar` me devuelve como `null` el Id, la idea es, que cuando genere un nuevo comentario el Id se incremente.

A continuación les dejo el código de que inserta el comentario en la base de datos. Utilizo Visual Studio 2015 y SQL Server 2014

```
// Insertar un nuevo comentario
public int InsertarComentario(Comentarios comentarios)
{
    // Conectarse a la base de datos
    SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TecnoInfoConnectionString"]);

    // Conectarnos
    conexion.Open();

    // Ejecutar la consulta
    // Creamos la sentencia
    SqlCommand comando = conexion.CreateCommand();
    comando.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Comentarios (Comentario, IdUsuario, IdArticulo) OUTPUT INSERTED.IdComentario VALUES (@Comentario, @IdUsuario, @IdArticulo)";
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comentario", comentarios.Comentario);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdUsuario", comentarios.IdUsuario);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdArticulo", comentarios.IdArticulo);

    // Ejecutarla
    int nuevoIdComentario = (int)comando.ExecuteScalar(); //devuelve la primer columna de la primer fila
    comentarios.IdComentario = nuevoIdComentario;

    // Cerrar la conexion
    conexion.Close();

    // Devuelve el Id del nuevo articulo
    return nuevoIdComentario;
}
```

El error en especifico es el siguiente:

> "No se puede insertar el valor NULL en la columna 'IdComentario', tabla 'Tecno_Info.dbo.Comentarios'. 
>   La columna no admite valores NULL. Error de INSERT."

Comment: Vs 2015... Proyecto nuevo, personal y estas programando como hace 10 años? Utiliza linq . El código que tienes es demasiado propenso a errores

Comment: Jajajaj es de la forma que me enseñaron, hace poco mas de dos meses estoy con esto, igualmente voy a seguir tu consejo y voy a modernizarme un poco. Gracias!

Comment: En tu código  dice el comentario "// Insertar un nuevo comentario", y el parámetro dice Comentarios como tipo que recibe la variable "comentarios" también... seria bueno que si es un comentario la variable se llamase en singular, y si la clase no es una colección de comentarios tambien ("mis cinco centavos")

Comment: Gracias Jose por tu consejo, voy a tratar de ser un poco mas claro con los nombres de mis variables!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

piacquadio, como bien te comentan faltaba que sea IDENTITY la columna de la DB
(NOTA: Me sumo también a la recomendación que modularices tu app en capas, por ejemplo tu capa de datos que se comunique con algun ORM, Entity Framework, NHibernate, etc)

Volviendo a tu tema... si como esta tu codigo en la pregunta no te devolvera el ID que se insertó, falta algo:

**Retornar la columna identidad (clave) que se insertó con [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)**

Como podrás leer en [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx), dice

> Ejecuta la consulta y devuelve la primera columna de la primera fila del conjunto de resultados devuelto por la consulta.Las demás columnas o filas no se tienen en cuenta.

Por esta razon no devuelve la filas afectadas por el insert y ni mucho menos devuelve la clave (identity) que se insertó.
¿Como lo solucionamos?
Para eso nos ayudamos en SQL Server de [SCOPE_IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms190315.aspx). En tu ejemplo solo hay que agregar al final el SELECT de esta funcion del SQL, algo así:

```
//Ejemplo para devolver el Identity que insertó (al final SELECT...)
SqlCommand comando = conexion.CreateCommand();
comando.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Comentarios (Comentario, IdUsuario, IdArticulo) OUTPUT INSERTED.IdComentario VALUES (@Comentario, @IdUsuario, @IdArticulo); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
```

Alli, el SQL devolvera un SELECT con 1 columna 1 fila, que contiene en ella el valor que necesitas.

Enlaces que te pueden servir de ayuda o guía

- [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)
- [SCOPE_IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms190315.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

El campo en la bd sql server debe ser de tipo identity para que el consecutivo de genere automáticamente.

Comment: Gracias! Era eso al final :)